# How can I consume Amazon S3 JavaScript APIs with AngularJS 2?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, angular

I am writing an Angular2 application. Can someone please tell me how I can consume S3 Javascript APIs from Angular2. Is it even possible?

Or is there a procedure through which I can use the javascript APIs from my typescript? I am using SystemJS for module loading.

Comment: What are you trying to do with S3? What you want to do will determine if it's possible.

Comment: I just want to do CRUD operations on buckets, download/upload files etc. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

http://www.spacevatican.org/2013/7/7/direct-to-s3-browser-uploads/

You need to generate a policy document signed by your access key to authorize the request. That would be done server-side for security reasons. There's nothing stopping you from using your access key directly except that then you'd be giving them full access to the whole bucket at minimum.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the AWS Javascript SDK for the browser available here -> https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-browser/

This is the main [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/index.html), its not be mistaken with the [Node API](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) which is also in Javascript.

According to the docs you can do calls to amazon s3 which is what you are looking for.

There is nothing special that you need to do in an Angular 2 program to make this work, Angular 2 is compatible out of the box with third part APIs.

If you run into issues like things not getting updated on the screen, you can wrap your call in an [NgZone run call](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/NgZone-class.html), but this in principle should not be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am new to Angular2. I couldn't find a procedure on how to consume an API defined in aws-sdk-2.3.18.js. Or how do I consume any external API in Angular2 should be the right question I should ask.

Comment: Hello, i think that the right question, have a look the last part of this answer in principle nothing special is needed. If you call the API it should just work, but if it doesn't you can always try NgZone